# Google login in eclipse causes error of "Cookies are off.Please Turn on"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, cookies, google-plugin-eclipse

I am building App Engine applications in Eclipse (Juno). When I tried to signin to Google in Eclipse, I am getting the message "Your cookies are turned off. Make it on". How do I enable cookies in Eclipse? My system default browser supports cookies no problem with Google signin. Please help me so that I can upload my application to Google's server.

Thanks in Advance,
Sasi Krishna

Answer (score 1):

user2292916 is correct that Eclipse uses Internet Explorer's cookie settings for Windows users, but note that you can keep your current privacy settings by just allowing Google to store cookies.

- Start Internet Explorer
- Open Internet Options
- Open the Privacy tab and select Sites
- Add "google.com"
- Restart Eclipse

You should now be able to deploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

You did not receive an answer yet. But you can use a bat file to deploy an application:

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=john.doe@gmail.com --passin update C:\Eclipse\workspace\yourappid < "C:\john_doe_his_password.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me turning on cookies in Internet Explorer helped.

My default browser is Chrome, and I had cookies turned on, but I could not manage to login until I turned them on for IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running **Eclipse on Windows**, for some unknown reason to me, Eclipse uses **Internet Options** settings. So to fix the problem,

go to **Control Panel** -> **Internet Options**

go to **Privacy** tab page

set the security level to the lowest possible (**"Accept All Cookies"**).

(Note: donat3llo mentioned the same solution in above)