# Why cookie is not setting in the Google chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am wokring in Eclipse and trying to set a cookie. But it didn't work. 
I have tried the code in W3schools "try it yourself". It works fine. But when I run it from eclipse it doesn't set cookie.
Here is my code for setting a cookie using javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
    {
    c_end = c_value.length;
    }
  c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly advise me on that issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/nXy33/1/. When you said eclipse do you mean this? http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/ May be it doesn't have cookie support. Why does it matter if your code works on browsers but not in your IDE?

Comment: @j03w I also tried it in jsfiddle already it worked fine. when i run the html from visual studio it works fine. I found the cookie in the browser. But when I run from Eclipse IDE it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with the code or browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695743/google-login-in-eclipse-causes-error-of-cookies-are-off-please-turn-on this may help you

Comment: @j03w it's not working. I have followed the instructions suggested by you, but it didn't set cookie.